# How can I get unkown input in c++ and recognize the type of that value?

Tags: c++, input, types

Is there any way to get Unknown input in c++?

I mean if we want to get an " int number " we should use this code:

```
int main()
{
    int x; //now we can get int number
    cout <<"Enter your number: ";
    cin >> x;
    cout << "The number is: " << x;
    return 0;
}
```

but if I dont know the type of value which user enter as an input how can I get that? should I use something like this :

```
unknown x; //to get unknown value?
```

And after I get that value how can I recognize what type is it?

for exp:

```
unknown x;
if ( x = int x )
{
cout << "The value is an int number";
}
```

I am amatuar in c++ so simple explanations would be better.thanks

Comment: take a look at the keyword `auto`

Comment: You need to accept input as a string and then figure out what it is. Check for numerical digits, decimal points, etc.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Is there any other way? *_* . this may need lots of codes .

Comment: @TheEpic -- *And after I get that value how can I recognize what type is it?* -- This is an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/).  What high-level problem are you really trying to solve?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I just wanted to find out Is there any solution or not . bcz there is no answer for my question on the web .

Comment: @TheEpic Not reallt. You can use [std::stod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) for example, or the integer variants. If by "any value" you mean a number, or not a number. Otherwise you need to specify your question more.

Comment: There is no answer because a program always knows what the input should be.  If your program expects an integer, then you check if it's an integer.  If your program expects the input to start with the letter `X`, you check if the input starts with the letter `X``.  There is no such thing as "unknown input" -- either the input is valid according to the program specs, or it isn't.  Thus you write the code, call a function, etc. to check the input's validity.

Comment: "this may need lots of codes": yes, it needs **a lot** of code to be written. If you don't want to write that code, find a programmer which is willing to write the code for you, or one who already wrote that code: a library. Even better, use Python, in which **a lot** of code has already been written and packaged exactly to deal with the "I don't want to think to types, please do it for me".

Comment: If you want to solve this problem yourself (and, as @PaulMcKenzie already said, probably you don't need to), you should look into polymorphism, making a generic type and then a factory method which gets a string and returns the correct type. But I bet you don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do, is to follow the general rules for all IO operations: Check the functions result.

If a IO function does not succeed, then 1 or more failure indication bits will be set.

You will find a very nice description in the CPP reference [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base/iostate).

What you will notice additionally, is that the `!` and `bool` operator is overloaded. Please see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator!) and [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool). With that, it is very simple to check the result of an IO-operation.

Example. Let us assume that you want to open a stream to a file.

```
// Open text file
std::istream fileStream{"test.txt"};
```

To check, if that worked, you can write

```
// Check, if open worked
if (fileStream)  // bool operator will be invoked
    std::cout << "Success\n";
```

Negative test can be done with:

```
// Check, if open proble
if (!fileStream)  // ! operator will be invoked
    std::cout << "Problem\n";
```

OK, next, the IO operation:

```
int x; std::cin >> x;
```

You may have read that the extractor `>>` and the inserter `<<` operator, return a reference to the stream for which they were invoked. With that a chain of operations can be done:

```
int x,y,z; std::cin >> x >> y >> z;
```

How does this work? So, first the operation `std::cin >> x` is done. which return `std::cin`. Then the line reads like `std::cin >> y >> z`. Y is extracted and again `std::cin` is returned. Now we have `std::cin >> z`. Z is extracted and return `std::cin`. And `std::cin` has the bool operator overloaded. This can be checked with a simple if:

```
int x;
if (std::cin >> x) {
    std::cout << "Integer value " << x << " read\n";
}
else {
    std::cerr << "\nError while reading an integer value\n";
}
```

So, you cannot enter nonesense like "abc". If an integer can be converted from the input, it will do that. Caveat with things like "1,23".

We can also combine this with additional criterea. And this with the help of boolean shortcut evaluation:

```
int x;
if (std::cin >> x and x >= 0 and x<= 100) {
    // Do something
}
else
{
    std::cerr << "\nWrong input\n";
}
```

The above will get a number betwenn 0..100.

So, for the future, check the result of IO operations . . .

---

If you really want to read unknown data types, then please read a string and parse it. Either by handcrafted analysis or by parsing techniques.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be possible to declare a variable's type at runtime, because types must be known at compile time. You could try to use the boost libraries:

```cpp
boost::variant<std::string, int, float, char> x;
```

but then it would be cumbersome to identify the intended type of whatever the user inputs.

For your second question, you could use `typeid(x).name()`, where x is the name of the variable you want to find the type of; however, this returns a mangled result, which is fine if you're using MSVC since it automatically handles the demangling for you, but not so great if you're using another compiler. If you're using another compiler, you have to demangle the result of calling `typeid(x).name()`, and for that, I would recommend looking at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/ext_demangling.html

Edit: You need to `#include <typeinfo>` to use `typeid(x)`

Comment: But even if you use `boost::variant` or even `std::any`, how would `std::cin` know what to do? The problem is also ambiguous, if I enter `123`, did I mean an `int`, a `float` or a `std::string`?

Comment: I think the only way would be to do as Retired Ninja commented in the original question, figuring out the intended type by checking for numerical digits, characters, or decimal points. That's what I mean by it would be cumbersome to identify the intended type of whatever the user inputs.

Answer (score -2):

i write a program like this to judge :

read it as a string and we write judge-fuctions

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
using namespace std;
struct unknown
{
    private: char ch[1024];
    public: void Input()
    {
        scanf("%s",ch);
        return ;
    }
    public: bool IsInt()
    {
        bool flg=true;
        for(int i=0;i<(int)strlen(ch);i++)
        if(ch[i]<'0'||ch[i]>'9')
        {
            flg=false;
            break;
        }
        return flg;
    }
};
int main()
{
    unknown x;
    x.Input();
    if(x.IsInt())
    printf("Int");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can add more function to judge is it a string etc.

Comment: The idea is good, but the execution, not so good. Better use `std::string` instead of `char[1024]` (to prevent overflow) and `std::stoi` for the `IsInt` function (to simplify).

Comment: Might also use `std::getline` instead of `scanf` since this is C++ and the vague description of the problem did not rule out spaces.